# What happended to the ability to expand parent groups in the Manage Groups page?

Tags: groups, 4.7

The Manage Groups page used to show a little icon you could click in order to see the child groups of a parent group. Now, under 4.7.6 there are no icons. This means you can't see or manage the child groups. This is a major issue for us. 
Any suggestions for how to fix this. Is it a bug?

Answer (score 2):

As you noted in the comments below, [there is a JIRA discussion about this issue](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18437). The issue has been tracked down, and a patch submitted (which is now in Q&A and slated for 4.7.8).

Per @jitendrapurohit on the Jira thread above:

> Submitted a PR - https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/8323
>
> 1) First issue mentioned above was the regression of CRM-18184. Seems
>   the patch attached on that was different from the PR submitted. This
>   was later fixed in this PR
>   https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/8020
>
> 2) Second point was a regression of [this commit](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/9c3f979fa4a51aaae9b7347c8bbe156cf483eab5#diff-b29ed63288165d839769d883ef98f51cR53). The updated params
>   loses the key('parentsOnly') sent from $_GET.

Comment: I have no little triangles. BTW, using CiviCRM with latest Drupal.

Comment: Just guessing -- maybe a Javascript error on the page? Is everything else looking normal?

Comment: Everything else is normal. No errors. It's weird.

Comment: Also tried it in different web browsers just in case.

Comment: I just tested on another site I have that is running 4.7.5 and I may have the same thing. The test I did earlier was on the demo server. I will try to test further later today.

Comment: Just tried the demo server. There I see the triangles. However, I note that it is running 4.7.8, not 4.7.6, so perhaps this is a bug that has been fixed.

Comment: Yes, maybe next official release will solve it...

Comment: Just found this bug: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18437 . However, they say it is not reproducible. Perhaps that person is also using the demo server with 4.7.8.